# How do I restrict created users to a directory and disable SSH for VSFTPD

Tags: centos, permissions, ftp, users

I've been googling for my answers for a good few hours and I can't seem to get a direct answer to my questions. I have found many tutorials but many are vague.

Anyways:

I've recently setup VSFTPD on my server. I'm running CentOS 6.4 (if that makes any difference). I have created the user 'test' using useradd and it can login successfully (with SSH and FTP) However this is what I'm looking to do:

Create users (with useradd) to use with VSFTPD and disable SSH for them. With these user(s) restrict them to their web directory (e.g. /var/www/domain/example.com) so they can login with FTP and upload, edit, delete and create directories with in the example.

For reference this is my configuration file:

> > anonymous_enable=NO
>
> local_enable=YES
>
> write_enable=YES
>
> local_umask=022
>
> dirmessage_enable=YES
>
> xferlog_enable=YES
>
> connect_from_port_20=YES
>
> xferlog_std_format=YES
>
> chroot_local_user=YES chroot_list_enable=YES
>
> listen=YES
>
> pam_service_name=vsftpd userlist_enable=YES tcp_wrappers=YES

Many thanks. Apologises if my explanation isn't descriptive enough. I'm not sure how to word it.

Comment: To disable users in SSHD, use the whitelist function : `AllowUsers` followed by a list of allowed usernames.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming you're mostly asking how to prevent a user being able to use SSH as - as far as I can tell - your vsftpd config should be good to go based on the chroot_local_user option being set to yes.

You can simply change the user's shell to something like /bin/false (make sure to add it to /etc/shells to prevent possible problems with the ftp server) and your user will be able to authenticate to SSH but they'll just get dumped back out.

Alternatively you *could* use AllowUsers/DenyUsers in /etc/ssh/sshd_config - but this could require updating the ssh config every time you change who's allowed to login, whereas you can set the user's shell to /bin/false with your useradd command by using

```
useradd -s /bin/false <everything else>
```

Then if you later want to grant them SSH access you can just use usermod to change their shell to bash (for example).

Comment: Thank you. This solves half of my problem. I now need to know how to restrict users to a directory and not be able to go out of it. Do you know how I can restrict a user to a directory and not have them be able to go above it ?

Comment: Over ftp? Isn't chroot_local_user for that?

Comment: Are you sure they're using ftp to login and not sftp? And did you restart vsftpd after making config changes?